# All plugins has been deactivated with error - The plugin has been deactivated due to an error: Plugin file does not exist in Wordpress in Docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` for running a wordpress website using already existing code base.

```
version: "3.9"
    
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql-dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin123
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8081:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin123
    networks:
      - wpsite
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "8001:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
    volumes:
      - "../../blogs:/var/www/html"
      - "../../blogs/plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins"
networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

Here I map the existing code in the `blogs` folder to the `/var/www/html` and so as the `plugins` folder. But this doesn't seems to be working. It will be helpful if someone can point me in right direction.

Comment: Could you check permissions for blogs directory ? I think `www-data` is the expected user.

Comment: blogs directory is my repository folder only and it is not inside the container.

Comment: Blogs directory seems to be used inside your container too. If user running the app within this container has no right on blogs, it may cause an issue with plugins. You may try to change group ownership too ([user]:www-data)